# DefinedName Unexpected Keyword Argument Value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been trying to make DefinedName work but I have not been able to by following the documentation. I'm trying to programmatically create two dropdowns filled up with a list and filter. Where the second dropdown value changes based on the selection of the first one. Below is the code I have so far, my current issue is:
`TypeError: DefinedName.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'`
but value parameter is an accepted keyword based on the docs: [Docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.html?highlight=DefinedName)

Any help is really appreciated!

code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl.workbook.defined_name import DefinedName

# Create a new workbook and select the active sheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Define the options for the first dropdown
dropdown1_values = ['Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Meat']

# Define the options for the second dropdown based on the selection of the first dropdown
dropdown2_values = {
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'],
    'Vegetable': ['Carrot', 'Broccoli', 'Tomato'],
    'Meat': ['Chicken', 'Beef', 'Pork']
}

# Define the ranges for the dropdowns
dropdown1_range = 'A1:A10'
dropdown2_range = 'B1:B10'

# Write the options for the first dropdown to the worksheet
for value in dropdown1_values:
    ws.append([value])

# Create a DataValidation object for the first dropdown
dv1 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=f'={ws.title}!$A$1:$A${len(dropdown1_values)}')
dv1.ranges = [dropdown1_range]  # Assign the range directly
ws.add_data_validation(dv1)

# Create a named range for the second dropdown options
named_range = f'{ws.title}!$B$1:$B${len(dropdown2_values["Fruit"])+1}'
named_range_obj = DefinedName(name="dropdown2_options", localSheetId=0, hidden=True, value=f'{ws.title}!{named_range}')
wb.defined_names.append(named_range_obj)

# Add a change event to the first dropdown to update the formula of the named range
dv1.add('A1', formula=f'=INDIRECT("dropdown2_options")')

# Save the workbook
wb.save('dropdowns_with_filters.xlsx')
```

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/defined_name.html#DefinedName) `value` is not in `__init__` but it looks like it is  supposed to be an alias for `attr_text` Try using that param instead.

Comment: The signature of the constructor and the linked source code don't mention a parameter `value`. It seems to be an error in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to attr_text fixed the problem.